# The bookmarks stopped to work in my website URLs

Tags: html

The bookmarks stopped to work in my website URLs.

For example: http://www.website.com/page#91

doesn't slide anymore the page to the `<div id="91">`.. and it was perfectly working before.

It just open the page from beginning, or last slided position.

Comment: Is the anchor (91) still there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, the issue was that I hided it with css.

If the element is not displayed, it doesn't work.

I know, it sounds obvious, but the point is that I was using an empty element just to slide the page.